# Writing a PNG file to disk in a Jest test is extremely slow

Tags: node.js, png, jestjs

I'm seeing the exact same code take **thirty** seconds to run in a Jest test compared to only **four** seconds in a Node script.

I've pinpointed the problem to a line that uses [pngjs](https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) to write a PNG to the file system. The [CPU profile](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1845257/33592411-7b03cd78-d950-11e7-91f3-3756dab16374.png) that I took seems to indicate that the issue lies within `pngjs`
 in the `paethPredictor` and `filterSum` functions, but as I mentioned earlier the slowdown only happens within the Jest test.

I'm using the most recent LTS version of Node (8.9.2) and the most recent version of Jest (21.2.1). The issues has occurred on both Windows and macOS.

See [this repository and README](https://github.com/mattblang/jest-image-comparison-perf-repro) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just a thought – why not just mock out pixelmatch? Is your intention to actually test the pixelmatch lib, or your code, that uses pixelmatch. If the latter, I would use a mock instead of the real pixelmatch. If the former – well, it would actually be the job of the authors of  pixelmatch to write tests for their lib, wouldn't it?

Comment: @PatrickHund So actually what I am doing is using a library from Google called [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to take screenshots along with a [matcher](https://github.com/americanexpress/jest-image-snapshot) from Amex that leverages the snapshotting features of Jest for an image screenshot rather than a virtual DOM snapshot.